# Java client app freezes when sending object through sockets

Tags: java, sockets, object, stream

i have this client/server application, and the client application sometimes completely freezes when i try send object via sockets

```
public Client client = new Client();
petriNetList = client.query(client.actionLoadPetriNetList, MainWindow.loginUsername);
```

here is the code of the client

```
 public class Client {
    public static Socket kkSocket = null;
    public static PrintWriter out = null;
    public static BufferedReader in = null;
    public static BufferedReader stdIn = null;
    public static OutputStream outputStream = null ;
    public static ObjectOutputStream  objectOutputStream = null ; 
    public static InputStream inputStream = null ; 
    public static ObjectInputStream  objectInputStream = null ;  


    public String actionSavePetriNet = "SAVE PETRI NET START";



    /*
     * Save petri net to server
     * 
     * @param action identifies query
     * @param petriName name of the petri net
     * @param username username
     * @param xml content of the petri net
     * 
     * @return int response form server
     */
public int query (String action,String petriName,String username,String xml) throws IOException {



    int size ;
    int result = 0;
    connect();
    if (action.equals(actionSavePetriNet)) {

        out.println(action); // save petri net
        out.println(petriName); //petri net name
        out.println(username); //username
        System.out.println("(Client:)" + xml);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(xml); //send object over the network
        System.out.println("Dostali sme sa sem ?");
        result = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()); //read response from server
    }

       disconnect();
        return result;
}    


    /*
     * connect to server
     * TODO: ADD hostname and port as parameter
     */
    public static void connect() throws IOException {
    try {
            kkSocket = new Socket("osiris-PC", 4444);
            out = new PrintWriter(kkSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(kkSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

         stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

          outputStream = kkSocket.getOutputStream();  
          objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);  

          inputStream = kkSocket.getInputStream();
          objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

    }

    /*
     * Disconnect from server
     * close all input/output streams
     * 
     */
    public static void disconnect() throws IOException {
        out.close();
        in.close();
        stdIn.close();
        objectOutputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        objectInputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        kkSocket.close();

    }
}
```

and this is the code of server

```
public class PetriServer {
    public static Protocol kkp = new Protocol();

    public static   InputStream inputStream = null ;
    public static   ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null ; 
    public static   OutputStream outputStream = null ;
    public static   ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null ;



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        kkp.loadUsers();

     while(true) {
         ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

            inputStream = null ;
            objectInputStream = null ; 
            outputStream = null ;
            objectOutputStream = null ;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();  
       objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);  

        outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
       objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
       inputLine = in.readLine();

        String inputLine;
 if (inputLine.equals("SAVE PETRI NET START")) {

            String petriName;
            String username;
            String xml ;
            String input;
            int result;
            int size ;

            petriName = in.readLine(); //read petri name

            System.out.println("(Server): prijali sme poziadavok na ulozenie " + petriName );


            username = in.readLine(); //read username
            System.out.println("(Server): poziadavok ide od usera: " + username);

          while(true) {

//this is the line where is occasionally freezes 
                xml = (String)objectInputStream.readObject(); //read object over the network
           if (!xml.isEmpty()) break; 
          }


          System.out.println("(Server):" + xml);

            result = kkp.savePetrinet(username, petriName,xml); //save it to the file
            out.println(result);

        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        objectInputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        objectOutputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();


    }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what can be problem ?
cheers.

Comment: What does a thread dump of the client show when it's frozen?

Comment: It looks like you're using the socket's `InputStream` in two different contexts - one context is in your `BufferedReader`, and the other is calling it directly inside your `while(true)` loop on the Client.  This is inherently dangerous - I'd either use the BufferedReader all the time or the direct call to the InputStream all the time, but mix them (each maintains their own state and BufferedReader might be broken if your direct call to InputStream interferes with its internal state).  What happens if, instead of calling the InputStream in the loop, you read from the BufferedReader instead?

Comment: nwinkler - dump is empty, there is no output, Ben Lawry - im not sure if i get what you mean, i dont have any while(true) loop on the client, and with BufferedReader im not sure how to read object, that client send, becuase there is no "readObject" method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Socket InputStream on the server attached to two different inputs, `ObjectInputStream` and `BufferedReader`.  `InputStreams` are not intended to be used this way, and doing so can cause a lot of problems.  BufferedReaders, by their nature, are going to be pulling more data off the `InputStream` than you are actually reading.  If they happen to buffer data that makes up an object, then your subsequent attempt to read the object off the `ObjectInputStream` will block, because the data has already been removed.

You need to pick one method or the other to read data.  If you need to be able to read both Strings and Objects off the Socket, then you will have to go to a byte-oriented mode of operation where you read the bytes off into a byte array, then process the byte array yourself to insure that you don't loose any data.

**Edit based on @Dunes comment below**

Seems your best bet is to stick entirely with `ObjectInputStream` and make use of its other methods that allow you to read arbitrary primitive types from the stream.  And, if you don't mind the deprecated call, it even has a `readLine` method.

Comment: Object input/output streams are highly versatile as they implement DataInput/DataOuput as well (letting you send any data type you want), so Podvedz should just stick to using object input/output streams rather than trying to do anything as fancy as you suggest.

Comment: So, ive decided that i will use only Object Input(Output) Stream, since they are the best solution i think , although i will have to rewrite some methods, since int is not an object, but fortunately, Integer is  :) it seems like its working so far

Comment: @PovedzHeslo, there is not need to rewrite the methods to use `Integer` objects.  `ObjectOutputStream` has a `writeInt()` method!  (Along with `writeByte()`, `writeDouble()`, etc)